# How to eliminate the multiindex in pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have the dataframe that you can see in figure A.
I want it to be like figure B, so that I can plot bars.
So, how can I eliminate all the indexes?

Here is my code:

```
    df2.reset_index('level_1',drop=True)
    df2.plot(kind='bar', subplots=True, figsize=(13,15), legend=False)
```

Figure A

[image: Figure A]

Figure B
[image]

Comment: Hard to diagnose (for me) .. what is the output if you do`df2.columns.name` and `df2.index.name`?

Comment: Please don't post your data as images... Read [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [how to create good reproducible pandas examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: okey. I will be more careful when posting images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have a hierarchical index for either your index or your columns. What you are seeing is the names of the index and the columns. `level_0` is the name for the columns and `level_1` is the name for the index. They should not affect any code. If you want to eliminate them you can do `del df.index.name` and `del df.columns.name` or set them equal to an empty string.

See this sample dataframe with no names for index or columns

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3], 'b':[2,4,5]})
```

[image]

Now, lets add names to both the index and columns

```
df.columns.name = 'level_0'
df.index.name = 'level_1'
```

[image]

And get rid of them again

```
del df.columns.name, df.index.name
```

Comment: You are right! It was not necessary to remove the names of index and columns. The reason I could not plot was because I forgot to put: %matplotlib inline